# How can I style a <span> tag as a Vuetify input label?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to have a `<span>` styled as a Vuetify input label.

[image]

Styled as "Regular" label. Is there anything like this?

```
<span class="vuetify-label">Regular</span>
```

Comment: You can open your browser devtools, find a cool class name and style it with CSS yourself mainly. Otherwise, check for a dedicated "style" prop or alike on Vuetify's side but if it doesn't exist, don't sweat it too much and use CSS.

Comment: @kissu the idea behind using a hypothetical Vuetify class is to keep them aligned if Vuetify updates.

Comment: Then, a custom one is still the best way to go because you will not need to follow any breaking changes. You can keep your own style + preference without relying on their framework.

Comment: @kissu I don't need to have my own style. I want to rely on the framework.

Comment: If the framework does not provide such thing, the solution is to use? A custom CSS selector and apply some homemade styling. Not sure what different you're expecting here.

Comment: @kissu well, I expect a solution which doesn't involve to follow framework style changes. Vuetify labels currently have a greysh color; I don't want to manually change my CSS if Vuetify developers decide to go from greysh to black.

Comment: You can always reference of their CSS global variables. Otherwise, you can never predict what will be the future potential breaking changes. Creating your own framework is a solution tho. Otherwise, front-end is moving quickly so don't expect a working solution for years with a simple trick.

Comment: @kissu do you have any idea on how to reference their CSS global vars?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slot="label"` to extend as per your need. Here is the working example

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
})
```

```css
.vuetify-label {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col
            cols="12"
            sm="6"
            md="3"
          >
            <v-text-field
              label="Regular"
            >
              <template slot="label">
              <span class="vuetify-label">Your custem label</span>
              </template>
            </v-text-field>
          </v-col>
  
        
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what I need. I just need a random <span> tag styled as a Vuetify input label. Only the label.

Comment: If you are working in a framework you have to use its functionality.. you can use prop to extend..  otherwise, you can write your own classes and use them as normal html/css

Comment: The idea behind using a hypothetical Vuetify class is to keep my <span> tag style aligned with Vuetify one if framework updates. Just to be clear, my <span> tag and <v-text-field> are completely disconnected; they only have in common the label style.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vuetify's SASS variables to do this. Just do the following-

First, import the input API's SASS file in your current component, like this-

```css
@import "~vuetify/src/components/VInput/_variables.scss";
```

By doing the above, all SASS variables are available in the current component, and you can use them for your custom element. The full example would be-

```html
    <style lang="scss">
    @import "~vuetify/src/components/VInput/_variables.scss";
    
    .vuetify-label {
        height: $input-label-height !important;
        letter-spacing: $input-label-letter-spacing !important;
    }
    </style>
```

The list of all available input SASS variables is [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-input/#sass).

You can also look into the [v-text-field's SASS variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#sass) and use them as per your need.